# Nextcloud : Bad Headers detection

Tags: apache, http, https, archlinux, nextcloud

I'm actually encounter a problem with Nextcloud 14 (**clean install**)

> There are some warnings regarding your setup.
>
> Use of the the built in php mailer is no longer supported. Please update >your email server settings ↗.
>
> The "X-XSS-Protection" HTTP header is not set to "1; mode=block". This is a potential security or privacy risk, as it is recommended to adjust this setting accordingly.
>
> The "X-Content-Type-Options" HTTP header is not set to "nosniff". This is a potential security or privacy risk, as it is recommended to adjust this setting accordingly.
>
> The "Referrer-Policy" HTTP header is not set to "no-referrer", "no-referrer-when-downgrade", "strict-origin" or "strict-origin-when-cross-origin". This can leak referer information. See the W3C Recommendation ↗.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Gso.png)

Like you could see above nextcloud explicitly say than i don't have this header correctly configured :

But in my httpd.conf (I Use Arch BTW <3 ) :

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

I don't understand why it's not working, I even tried see which header are used and this header is used :

```
Request URL: https://cloud.schmitt-etienne.fr/index.php/settings/admin/overview
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [2a01:e34:eeab:eb60:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff]:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-length: 27725
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 18:22:45 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
referrer-policy: same-origin
server: Apache
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.10
x-robots-tag: none
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: cloud.schmitt-etienne.fr
:method: GET
:path: /index.php/settings/admin/overview
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie:
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
```

You could go see my website yourself if you want to [see yourself :](https://cloud.schmitt-etienne.fr/)

If i miss anything I missed I'm happy to hear any comment !

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found than nextcloud come included with a .htaccess who set his own header, so the headers was send two times and that was the cause :)

Never stop trying and learning !